How to redirect DNS traffic to dnsmasq on Android
I’m trying filter all DNS traffic using dnsmasq on Android (LineageOS). Here is what I did (thanks to the help of @IrfanLatif):

I installed it using termux:
pkg i root-repo && pkg up && pkg i dnsmasq
Then:
cp /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/dnsmasq /system/bin/

On Linux it's possible to divert traffic to dnsmasq simply by editing /etc/resolv.conf and replacing nameserver 8.8.8.8 with nameserver 127.0.0.1.
But on Android there is no such file, however I can achieve the same using an iptables command (divert all DNS queries to port 5353):
/system/bin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5353
/system/bin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5353


I create the file /etc/dnsmasq.conf containing:
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
no-poll
port=5353 # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< PORT
listen-address=127.0.0.1
no-hosts
expand-hosts
cache-size=500
log-queries

server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4

# Rules:
# Test block:
address=/bing.com/0.0.0.0


Now I can already start dnsmasq using the command:
/system/bin/dnsmasq --pid-file --conf-file=/etc/dnsmasq.conf <&-
I can also look at the logs and see that dnsmasq is running:
logcat | grep dnsmasq
05-27 19:17:08.039  7988  7988 D dnsmasq : forwarded google.com to 8.8.8.8
05-27 19:17:08.039  7988  7988 D dnsmasq : forwarded google.com to 8.8.4.4

But on the phone there is no internet access. This is the first problem I am having.

The second problem happens when I try to start dnsmasq on startup. Thanks to the input from @IrfanLatif, I flashed Magisk, and I have access to setpriv command.
However, when I try to set a UID to dnsmasq:
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/setpriv --reuid=999 --regid=999 --clear-groups /system/bin/dnsmasq --pid-file --conf-file=/etc/dnsmasq.conf <&-
I get the error:
dnsmasq: failed to find list of interfaces: Permission denied
This is the second problem I'm having. I'm still trying to figure out what's going on. Any help from anyone will be much appreciated.



Recent Android versions have in the extended network settings an entry to specify a private DNS server. This setting is intended to specify a large DNS server like Google or Cloudflare which is capable of DNS over HTTPS or something similar, so I don't know what happens if you point it to a standard DNS server that uses UDP without further protection.

@ellat it will create a closed loop. You need to run dnsmasq with an unused UID (like 999) and then bypass it from redirection using iptables ... --uid-owner ....

@ellat you need to use something like setpriv or priv_exec (it's mine), not chown. Also you need to do iptables ... --uid-owner 999 ... -j ACCEPT, not ... -j DNAT ... (i.e. send these packets to internet, not to 127.0.0.1:53).

@ellat it's quite simple if you understand the basics of Linux commandline and networking. See explanation in my answer here.
